# RuntimeException ao usar colorbar() IDE Spyder

Tags: python, deep-learning, spyder

Estou um código para mostrar o uso de mapas auto organizáveis e aparece erro de execução ao usar a função colorbar.

O erro acontece na linha `colorbar()`. Antes disso a saída era:

[image: Saida]

Então, quando eu executo a linha `colorbar()`. Aparece o seguinte erro:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-dffe8fcb3a04> in <module>
----> 1 colorbar()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in colorbar(mappable, cax, ax, **kw)
   2091         mappable = gci()
   2092         if mappable is None:
-> 2093             raise RuntimeError('No mappable was found to use for colorbar '
   2094                                'creation. First define a mappable such as '
   2095                                'an image (with imshow) or a contour set ('

RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).
```

```py
# Self Organizing Map

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Credit_Card_Applications.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
X = sc.fit_transform(X)

# Training the SOM
from minisom import MiniSom
som = MiniSom(x = 10, y = 10, input_len = 15, sigma = 1.0, learning_rate = 0.5)
som.random_weights_init(X)
som.train_random(data = X, num_iteration = 100)

# Visualizing the results
from pylab import bone, pcolor, colorbar, plot, show
bone()
pcolor(som.distance_map().T)
colorbar()
markers = ['o', 's']
colors = ['r', 'g']
for i, x in enumerate(X):
    w = som.winner(x)
    plot(w[0] + 0.5,
         w[1] + 0.5,
         markers[y[i]],
         markeredgecolor = colors[y[i]],
         markerfacecolor = 'None',
         markersize = 10,
         markeredgewidth = 2)
show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu estava usando o Jupyter Notebook, e estava usando instruções separadas para fazer a parte de mostrar o mapa. O problema desapareceu quando executei todo esse trecho de uma só vez, ao invés de fragmentar a execução do mesmo.

```py
from pylab import bone, pcolor, colorbar, plot, show

# Initializing the figure that contains the map
bone()
pcolor(som.distance_map().T)
colorbar()
markers = ['o', 's'] # circles and squares
colors = ['r', 'g'] # red and green

# i for lines and X for vector that represents the customer
for i, x in enumerate(X):
    w = som.winner(x) # the winning node of customer x
    plot(w[0] + 0.5, 
         w[1] + 0.5,
         markers[Y[i]],
         markeredgecolor = colors[Y[i]],
         markerfacecolor = 'None',
         markersize=10,
         markeredgewidth=2) # +0.5 to plot on the center of square on the map

show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Desconfio que haja uma chamada à `show` logo após `pcolor` pois:

- Um gráfico é exibido
- A função `show` ["consome"](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/calling-show-twice-in-a-row-td22682.html) os gráficos feitos anteriormente - e portanto é natural que a chamada à `colorbar` falhe, visto que não há mais gráficos para aplicar o gráfico de barras
- O seguinte trecho de código também causa a mesma exceção que lhe ocorreu:

```py
from pylab import bone, pcolor, colorbar, show
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dados = np.clip(np.random.randn(20, 20), -1, 1)
bone()
pcolor(dados)
show()
colorbar()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9f16f12cc15b> in <module>()
      7 pcolor(dados)
      8 show()
----> 9 colorbar()

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in colorbar(mappable, cax, ax, **kw)
   2319         mappable = gci()
   2320         if mappable is None:
-> 2321             raise RuntimeError('No mappable was found to use for colorbar '
   2322                                'creation. First define a mappable such as '
   2323                                'an image (with imshow) or a contour set ('

RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).
```

---

Se esse for o caso, vejo algumas possibilidades:

- Durante o desenvolvimento, você acrescentou temporariamente uma chamada à `show` após a chamada à `pcolor` para testar o andamento do programa? Se sim, basta retirá-la - em outras palavras, o código que você compartilhou, com apenas um `show`, já deve estar funcionando.
- Sua IDE pode fazer chamada implícita à função `show`. Para verificar, você pode salvar o código que você fez em um arquivo `.py`, e rodar diretamente via console.